# Add objects to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdictionary

I want to populate NSDictionary with text from UITextFields. Here is what I try

```
[self delegate]populate:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [self.username.text], @"username",
                                 [self.password.text], @"password"
                                 nil];
```

But I get expected identifier.
What is wrong here ? Why can't pass [self.*] directly ?

I have tried also

```
[self delegate]populate:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.username.text]], @"username",
                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.password.text]], @"password"
                                 nil];
```

still not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[self.username.text]` is invalid syntax.

The message sending syntax is `[object message]`. The dot syntax is `object.property`. Since a property access usually results in an object, you can combine them, but there still needs to be a message part. If you just put the dot syntax inside brackets, you're missing the message part: `[object.property <missing message>]`.

Change it to either `self.username.text` (no brackets) or `[self.username text]`.

As bdesham points out (I assumed this was just a typo here), you're missing braces around the whole snippet. `[self delegate]` is the object to which you're sending the message `populate`:

```
[[self delegate] populate:<another message send here, to NSDictionary>];
```

Comment: The OP also needs brackets around the entire expression: `[[self delegate] populate:...]`

Comment: I changed it to [self.username text]. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[[self delegate] populate:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [self.username.text], @"username",
                             [self.password.text], @"password"
                             nil]];
```

Looks like you are missing `[ ]` around the entire message!